# bolt manufacturing normal distribution problem

Tags: statistics

The diameter of a bolt in a manufacturing process distributes $N(μ,σ^2)$, a bolt is considered fit if it's diameter's deviation from the mean is less than 2.
What's the probability that a single bolt is fit?

I still don't have a very good grasp on normal distribution and am trying to learn through this excercise, would love to get some help.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Denote the diameter with $D$. Then a bolt is fit iff $|D-\mu|\le2$. So$$P(|D-\mu|\le2)=P(|Z|\le~?)$$where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. Can you complete?

---

As mentioned in the comments, since you seem to be expecting a numerical answer, I suspect by "deviation from the mean", your question could probably be meaning the quantity $\left|\frac{D-\mu}\sigma\right|$ instead of $|D-\mu|$.

In that case, we have $P\left(\left|\frac{D-\mu}\sigma\right|\le2\right)=P(|Z|\le2)=2P(0<Z<2)$. Now plug in the value of $P(0<Z<2)$ from the table. It is $0.4772$ so the answer is twice of that, i.e. $2\cdot0.4772=0.9544$.

Comment: really no idea where to go from there

Comment: See the edit...you can't really find the exact probability without knowing the value of $\sigma$

Comment: $(2-μ)/sqrt(σ)$?

Comment: $Z=\frac{D-\mu}\sigma$ so $P(|D-\mu|\le2)=P\left(\frac{|D-\mu|}\sigma\le\frac2\sigma\right)=P\left(|Z|\le\frac2\sigma\right)=2P(0<Z<2/\sigma)$.

Comment: and where do I go from there?

Comment: That's the farthest you can go without knowing the value of $\sigma$. I suspect by "deviation from the mean", your question could probably be meaning the quantity $\left|\frac{D-\mu}\sigma\right|$ instead of $|D-\mu|$. In that case, we have $P\left(\left|\frac{D-\mu}\sigma\right|\le2\right)=P(|Z|\le2)=2P(0<Z<2)$. Now plug in the value of $P(0<Z<2)$ from the table, it is $0.4772$ so the answer is twice of that.

Comment: I'm thinking the meaning of the question was $P(∣D−μ∣≤2σ)$ would that change anything?

Comment: I just talked about that possibility in my recent comment and edit. Then the answer will be twice of $0.4772$.